# To PyQt5 'connect' conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I try to make a conversion of some code from PyQt4 to PyQt5, however I have not ever worked with PyQt, that is why I have some problems with this. I failed to convert some code with .connect, because as I understand in PyQt5 work with signals and slots changed. Here is the code.

```
class Gui(QWidget.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, cfgpath):
        QWidget.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.configpath = cfgpath
        self.paint = Viewer(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        self.maskClearButton.clicked.connect(self.paint.clearMask)
        self.brushSizeSB.valueChanged.connect(self.brushSizeChange)
        btnlist = [self.horDownBtn, self.horDownLargeBtn, self.horUpBtn, self.horUpLargeBtn,
                   self.vertDownBtn, self.vertDownLargeBtn, self.vertUpBtn, self.vertUpLargeBtn]
        sigmap = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)
        for i in range(len(btnlist)):
            # Here it falls
            self.connect(btnlist[i], QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), sigmap, QtCore.SLOT("map()"))
            btnlist[i].clicked
            sigmap.setMapping(btnlist[i], i)
        # And here
        self.connect(sigmap, QtCore.SIGNAL("mapped(int)"), self.paint.handleScaleBtn)
```

So how can I change this code to make it work?

Comment: @eyllanesc It's pretty long and is loaded from some .ui file. If it is really needed I can share it using gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new connection style is as follows:

```
sender.signal.connect(slot)
```

In your case change:

```
self.connect(btnlist[i], QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), sigmap, QtCore.SLOT("map()"))

self.connect(sigmap, QtCore.SIGNAL("mapped(int)"), self.paint.handleScaleBtn)
```

to

```
btnlist[i].clicked.connect(sigmap.map)

sigmap.mapped.connect(self.paint.handleScaleBtn)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you have all the information needed for the new signal slot style: [pyqt new-style signal/slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)
Try and if you have any particular problem let me know.